# What is the typical half-life of a virus/worm on the internet?

Tags: malware, virus, research

I am curious about the typical half-life (i.e., loosely relating to radioactive [half-life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life) here), if one has been measured/estimated, for the average [virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus)/[worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_worm) on the internet.

- Has anyone done a detailed study of this?
- Is the half-life just tied to typical hardware and/or [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) lifetimes?

  - In other words, are viruses/worms limited to specific hardware and/or OS's?